# Ionic2 pushObject.on('notification') not working IOS

Tags: php, ios, ionic-framework, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I was trying to implement push notification on `ionic`.it is working properly and I am getting the notification when the app is closed. But the event was not triggering when the app is opened.
`pushObject.on('notification')` is not triggering.

I am using below PHP code to send the notifications:

```
 $deviceToken = $reg_id;
 $ctx = stream_context_create();
 // ck.pem is your certificate file
 stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $this->pemfile_path);
// stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'hourli123');
 // Open a connection to the APNS server
 $fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
 if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
 // Create the payload body
 $body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => array(
        'title' => "Hourli",
        'body'   => $message,
     ),
    'sound' => 'default'
 );
 $body['data'] = $data;
 // Encode the payload as JSON
 $payload = json_encode($body);
 // Build the binary notification
 $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
 // Send it to the server
 $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
 // Close the connection to the server
 fclose($fp);
```